# How to display an error for invalid input with php/html?

Tags: php, html

I've been working on some code for a registration page, with two separate files. (one for HTML and one for PHP) I've been trying to figure out how to display an error when an invalid input is submitted (such as password not strong enough) but I haven't been able to find anything that works. Is there a way for the PHP file to edit the HTML display when such an error is detected?

Comment: You can use AJAX for this. You can find examples online, for instance: https://www.formget.com/form-validation-using-ajax

Comment: When you get a response from the server, use CSS to highlight the problem in red.

Answer (score 0):

There can be two solutions:
#1. Use jQuery Validator and check your form before submitting it. It have a remote method where you can send an ajax request to put a server-side check as well.
https://jqueryvalidation.org/

#2. if both of your files are .php then you can use either of the following:

1. you can use the session to get a set error message.
2. you can define all possible errors in an array and when redirecting back to the HTML page just pass the error id/number in the URL parameter and on the display page get the URL parameter and display the message associated with that error id/number.